# sum of Bessel function of first kind and its asymptotic limit

Tags: integration, summation, asymptotics, bessel-functions

I wish to calculate the following sum,
$$A=\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\nu}(\xi)\delta(\nu-a)$$
where, $\xi=\beta\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$ and the sum needs to be calculated when $\beta\gg 1$.
I find in the literature that due to the limit on $\beta$ the sum could be converted to an integral over $\nu$ and the $\delta$ function would give,
$$A\approx J_{a}(\xi)$$
After this, the literature further evaluates the asymptotic value for $J_{a}(\xi)$ following two limits. While $a^2>\xi^2$, the asymptotic value of $J_{a}(\xi)$ is said to be evaluated from $K_{1/3}$, with $K_{1/3}$ being the modified Bessel function, on the other hand, if $a^2<\xi^2$ the asymptotic value said to be calculated from a combination of $J_{1/3}$ and $J_{-1/3}$.

I could not find a proper derivation of the calculation discussed above. It would be great to have some help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive it refers to the approximation of $J_a(\xi)$ in the transition region. Assume that $a \gg 0$. Nicholson found that
$$
J_a (\xi ) \approx \frac{1}{\pi }\sqrt {\frac{{2(a - \xi )}}{{3a}}} K_{1/3}\! \left( {\frac{{2^{3/2} (a - \xi )^{3/2} }}{{3a^{1/2} }}} \right) = \frac{{2^{1/3} }}{{a^{1/3} }}\operatorname{Ai}\left( {\frac{{2^{1/3} (a - \xi )}}{{a^{1/3} }}} \right)
$$
for $a\geq \xi$, and
\begin{align*}
J_a (\xi ) & \approx \frac{1}{3}\sqrt {\frac{{2(\xi  - a)}}{a}} \left[ {J_{  1/3} \!\left( {\frac{{2^{3/2} (\xi  - a)^{3/2} }}{{3a^{1/2} }}} \right) + J_{ - 1/3}\! \left( {\frac{{2^{3/2} (\xi  - a)^{3/2} }}{{3a^{1/2} }}} \right)} \right] \\ & = \frac{{2^{1/3} }}{{a^{1/3} }}\operatorname{Ai}\left( {\frac{{2^{1/3} (a - \xi )}}{{a^{1/3} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
for $a\leq \xi$. Here $\operatorname{Ai}$ denotes the Airy function. These formulae are discussed in G. N. Watson's book *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions* ($\S\S$8.43 starting on page 248). Watson does not discuss it, but these approximations are useful only when $\left| {\xi  - a} \right| = o(\left| a \right|^{9/15} )$. This condition follows from the [more general result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.E8) due to F. W. J. Olver. If you want approximations that are valid in larger domains, you can use the [uniform asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.20.E4) of $J_a(\xi)$.

Comment: Thank You @Gary for the answer. I will go through the resources that you have mentioned. I just have one more query, it would be great if you could shed some light on how to transform the summation to integration for a large argument. I mean the summation is in the integer-order but when we transform it to an integration we consider real numbers instead of integers. So I wanted to know how this transformation is taking place ?

Comment: @Sayan How do you define $\delta$ in the sum? Is $\delta(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: yes. $\delta(x)$ is defined the way you have mentioned.

Comment: But then the sum is just $J_a(\xi)$.

Comment: No. To put the value of $a$ at the place of $\nu$ you need to have an integration on $\nu$ first. I mean delta function follows the following rule, $$f(a)=\int f(x)\delta(x-a)dx$$, not $$f(a)=f(x)\delta(x-a)$$.

Comment: So your $A$ is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) then?

Comment: $A$ is function of $\xi$.

Comment: But $\delta$ is not a function in the usual sense. It is a distribution. Do you have a background in maths or do you have a background in physics/engineering?

Comment: Yes, but after integration it gives a single value, right? And if it is attached with a function then the integration will lead to the value of the function at a point where $\delta$ is non zero. Also I have a background in physics.

Comment: I asked it because physicists often do not care much about rigour and treat $\delta$ as a function, but it is not a function. What you say is correct. Your $A$ also has to be integrated against a function from a Schwartz space, say, to make sense. As a plain sum, it does not make sense from the mathematician's point of view.

Comment: Okay, please correct me if I am wrong,  lets say if I had something like, $$A=\sum \int J_{\nu}(\xi)\delta(x-k\nu)dk$$, with $\xi$ being a function of $k$, then it would had made sense, but as I am not having any integral there, the summation gives me back a distribution, as $\delta$ is a distribution by itself.

Comment: That is what I said a few comments before: $A$ is a distribution. For each $\xi$, it is a distribution in the variable $a$.

Comment: Another confusion @Gary, it might be a typo, shouldn't there be one $J_{1/3)$ and one $J_{-1/3)$ in the asymptotic form?

Comment: Of course, it was a typo.

Comment: I was going through the approximations of bessel functions and stuck at a question, might be a naive one, for my case the argument of the bessel function consists of $\xi$, which has the terms $\beta$, $\sin(\theta)$ and $\sin(\phi)$. Now sine functions are oscillatory functions, that means their value can approach very near to zero. So when it is said "in large argument limit" does it mean that the asymptotic approximation is valid for a narrow range of $\theta$ or $\phi$ value ? Because for some values of $\theta$ or $\phi$ the argument could get to 0.

Comment: The approximations I gave are valid around the transition point $a=\xi$ and for large $a$, so $\xi$ has to be large too. The uniform asymptotic expansions I linked are valid in larger domains but do not apply either when $\xi \to 0$. See the discussion [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.v). For an approximation that is valid for large positive $a$ and $0<\xi<1$, say, see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.i).

Comment: Thank you @Gary for the answer. Also for my case $-\beta<\xi<\beta$, where $\beta \gg 1$ and $a$ is very large. Would the same approximation be valid for this case, which was valid for large positive $a$ and $0<\xi<1$.

Comment: For negative argument use the fact that if $n$ is an integer then $J_n ( - z) = ( - 1)^n J_n (z)$.